# Prevent out of memory error when writing too much to the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got assigned the task of resolving a problem where I suspect too much data is attempting to be written to the browser. I.e Building tables to display on 2,000+ records.

```
$exception  {"Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."} System.Exception {System.OutOfMemoryException}
```

Exception is thrown on `Page_PreRender`

What is the easiest way to troubleshoot the problem?

What is the easiest way to test/resolve it?

Thanks

```
[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.String.Concat(String str0, String str1, String str2, String str3) +76
   ProgramName.File.GetData() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProgramName\File.aspx.cs:137
   ProgramName.File.Page_PreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ProgramName\File.aspx.cs:18
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +8775110
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +80
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +842
```

Comment: Are you using standard `table` or any jQuery library like `DataTables`?

Comment: What are the symptoms the user is experiencing that caused you to suspect that?

Comment: added exception message.

Comment: @JoJo The exception should give you the exact line number that caused this error (assuming you have the *.pdb files next to your *.dll files), at which point it should be fairly easy to determine the cause. Can you clarify what precisely is making your investigation hard? Also, please post the full stack-trace, as that might highlight something else. Finally, please post your `Page_PreRender` method.

Comment: @RB. It seems to be an error where it is looking for the other machine (i got the source code from) in the obj/Debug folder.. does that make sense to anyone? Can I just delete this folder? Or its possible I am opening it as a Web Site but it needs to be opened as a Project? I am not used to .DLL files in web sites..

Comment: @JoJo - the filenames in the stack trace will refer to the machine the software was built on - this is normal behaviour. However, it should give you the line-number of the line of code that is actually throwing this exception. I would suggest editing the question to include the stack-trace (feel free to redact any sensitive information such as real-names, etc.)

Comment: @RB. I added the StackTrace above. I added a dependent project and started it as a project. I am still getting OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @JoJo Thanks for the stack-trace - that gives the necessary information. Note that the stacktrace is telling you that the problem is on line 137 of `File.aspx.cs`, in the `GetData` method. You don't need to *guess* at where the problem might be - the computer is pointing a massive red arrow telling you **exactly** where to look :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the stack trace I think I know your problem.

In your `Page_PreRender` method you are concatenating strings (you mention that you are constructing a table - it's likely that it's the code doing this).

If you concatenate 2 strings together, memory get's allocated to create a new string to hold the result, but the memory to store the first two strings does not get reclaimed because those strings are still in scope. I'm guessing that you are concatenating a *lot* of strings (in a loop), and thus are running out of memory.

The fix is to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Find the code that looks something like this:

```
public void GetData() 
{
    string myTableString = "";
    foreach (var row in MyRows)
    {
        myTableString += "<tr><td>" + row.someProperty + "</td></tr>"
    }
```

to the following

```
using System.Text // This goes at the top of the file, with the other using statements.
...

public void GetData() 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var row in MyRows)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr><td>" + row.someProperty + "</td></tr>");
    }
    string myTableString = sb.ToString();
```

Note that the code I've given above is just my best guess at what your code looks like - it would be much easier if you posted your code!!

Comment: you my friend are a Genius! :) - I guess the list grew too large since the last guy wrote it and it broke! Thanks!